# Understanding CopyOnWriteArrayList iterator behavior

Tags: java, copyonwritearraylist

I am studying `CopyOnWriteArrayList` and the situation below got me thinking.

My main method goes like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Init1");
    list.add("Init2");
    list.add("Init3");
    list.add("Init4");

    for(String str : list){
        System.out.println(str);
        list.add("PostInit");
    }   
}
```

In the javadoc I read:

> Memory consistency effects: As with other concurrent collections, actions in a thread prior to placing an object into a CopyOnWriteArrayList happen-before actions subsequent to the access or removal of that element from the CopyOnWriteArrayList in another thread.

I was expecting an infinite loop since *"actions in a thread prior to placing an object into a CopyOnWriteArrayList happen-before actions subsequent to the access or removal"*.

But my console output is:

```
Init1
Init2
Init3
Init4
```

I believe, I lack some understanding here. Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation

> The "snapshot" style iterator method uses a reference to the state of
>   the array at the point that the iterator was created. This array never
>   changes during the lifetime of the iterator, so interference is
>   impossible and the iterator is guaranteed not to throw
>   ConcurrentModificationException. The iterator will not reflect
>   additions, removals, or changes to the list since the iterator was
>   created

The for-each loop is using the iterator, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2.

Therefore, the for-each loop is going to print the elements which are in the list at the moment the for-loop starts since it is at that moment the iterator is created.